# How do you change the way Visual studio Code format the code on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I have been working for a while now on Visual studio Code, And the way it format its code it just a pain the in the ass.

Look here is the code I wrote for example.

```
  var novelReader = (await repository.findOne<NovelReaderSettings>('ApplicationSettings')) ?? await repository.save(NovelReaderSettings.default());
```

You see a stright line now.Now look at the formated code.

```
    var novelReader =
            (await repository.findOne<NovelReaderSettings>(
              'ApplicationSettings',
            )) ?? (await repository.save(NovelReaderSettings.default()))
;
```

I liked the way I wrote it first and not now. How do I customize it to format it the way i want.

Comment: Do you have any formatters installed?  Prettier, etc. If so, disable them one by one and see if the formatting is still changed.

Comment: Yeas i have Prettier

Comment: That is probably the culprit.  If you disable it, is the formatting still changed?  I don't use Prettier you can see if it has an option that changes this behaviour but I don't think it has many options.

Comment: @Mark, after removing Prettier, the formatter started to work better. If you add it as an answer will mark as answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the file extension and what formatter you have configured for that type of file?

[Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) wouldn't ever do that, so if you let us know your settings we can figure out what's wrong.

Make sure you have it configured to the file type, for example, for javascript/react add these to your settings.json file:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```

You can configure Prettier to your preferred behaviour with lines like these:

```
"prettier.printWidth": 80,
"prettier.semi": true,
"prettier.singleQuote": true,
"prettier.tabWidth": 2,
"prettier.useTabs": false,
```

To get to your settings.json, go to the command palette and look for "Open settings (JSON), and add these lines in it.

Comment: I only have Prettier installed, where can i look to view the settings you want ? Im new to visual studio code

Comment: No problem. What's the file extension?

Comment: Prettier formatter, i have removed it now will test see how it look

Comment: Don't remove it, just configure it. Prettier is quite good. See my updated answer. And I meant what file type you were having your code in.

Comment: File settings? is it `.prettierrc` file?

Comment: you can have a .prettierrc file, but to assign Prettier to a determined filetype you need to edit settings.json, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: Where to find the settings.json file ?

Comment: I just described that in my last sentence in the answer :)